# Why does my preview continue to crash when I use a navigation link on swift ui?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to create a code that present different dog breeds with navigation links. My issue here is when I try to tap on the dutch shepherd my preview crashes. I have not added the navigation links to the other structs because I am having issue with the dutch shepherd one. The helper section tells me that a fatal error had occurred. Why am I unable to tap on the dutch shepherd without having my preview crash? Here is my code:

CONTENT VIEW

```
import SwiftUI

let dog: [DogSection] = Bundle.main.decode("dogdata.json")

struct DutchDetail: View {
    var body: some View {
    ForEach(dog) { section in
        NavigationLink(destination: { ForEach(dog) { item in
            HStack {
                Image("dutch_shepherd")
                Text(item.description)
            }
        }
        }) {
            Text(section.name)
        }
    }
}
}

struct HavaneseDetail: View {
var body: some View {
    List {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            Text("Havanese, the only dog breed native to Cuba, are vivacious and sociable companions and are especially popular with American city dwellers.")
        }
    }
}
}

struct ScottishDetail: View {
var body: some View {
    List {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            Text("A solidly compact dog of vivid personality, the Scottish Terrier is an independent, confident companion of high spirits. Scotties have a dignified, almost-human character.")
        }
    }
}
}

struct TosaDetail: View {
var body: some View {
    List {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            Text("A solidly compact dog of vivid personality, the Scottish Terrier is an independent, confident companion of high spirits. Scotties have a dignified, almost-human character.")
        }
    }
}
}

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: DutchDetail()) {
                HStack{
                    Image("dutch_shepherd")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                    Text("Dutch Shepherd")
                }
            }
            
            NavigationLink(destination: HavaneseDetail()) {
                HStack {
                    Image("havanese")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                    Text("Havanese")
                }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: ScottishDetail()) {
                HStack {
                    Image("scottish_terrier")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                    Text("Scottish Terrier")
                }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: TosaDetail()) {
                HStack {
                    Image("tosa")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                    Text("Tosa")
                }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Dog List")
            .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

HELPER

```
   import UIKit

extension Bundle {
func decode<T: Codable>(_ file: String) -> T {
    guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: "json") else {
        fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")//THIS IS THE FATAL ERROR THAT IS GETTING HIT
    }

    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
    }

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
        fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
    }

    return loaded
}
}
```

DOG

```
import SwiftUI

struct DogSection : Codable, Identifiable {
var id: String
var name: String
var description: String
var imageName: String
}
```

DOG DATA

```
import Foundation

[
{
    "id": "aa32jj887hhg55",
    "name": "Airedale Terrier",
    "description": "The Airedale stands among the world's most versatile dog breeds and has distinguished himself as hunter, athlete, and companion.",
    "imageName": "airedale_terrier"
},
{
    "id": "bb32jj887hhg77",
    "name": "American Foxhound",
    "description": "American Foxhounds are good-natured, low-maintenance hounds who get on well with kids, dogs, even cats, but come with special considerations for prospective owners.",
    "imageName": "american_foxhound"
},
{
    "id": "cc32jj887hhg66",
    "name": "Dutch Shepherd",
    "description": "The Dutch Shepherd is a lively, athletic, alert and intelligent breed, and has retained its herding instinct for which it was originally developed.",
    "imageName": "dutch_shepherd"
},
{
    "id": "dd32jj887hhg88",
    "name": "Havanese",
    "description": "Havanese, the only dog breed native to Cuba, are vivacious and sociable companions and are especially popular with American city dwellers.",
    "imageName": "havanese"
},
{
    "id": "ee32jj887hhg99",
    "name": "Leoberger",
    "description": "The Leonberger is a lush-coated giant of German origin. They have a gentle nature and serene patience and they relish the companionship of the whole family.",
    "imageName": "leonberger"
},
{
    "id": "ff32jj887hhg99",
    "name": "Mudi",
    "description": "The Mudi is an extremely versatile, intelligent, alert, agile, all-purpose Hungarian farm dog. The breed is a loyal protector of property and family members without being overly aggressive.",
    "imageName": "mudi"
},
{
    "id": "gg32jj887hhg99",
    "name": "Norwegian",
    "description": "From Norway’s rocky island of Vaeroy, the uniquely constructed Norwegian Lundehund is the only dog breed created for the job of puffin hunting. With puffins now a protected species, today’s Lundehund is a friendly, athletic companion.",
    "imageName": "norwegian_lundehund"
},
{
    "id": "hh32jj887hhg99",
    "name": "Pharaoh Hound ",
    "description": "The Pharaoh Hound, ancient \"Blushing Dog\" of Malta, is an elegant but rugged sprinting hound bred to course small game over punishing terrain. Quick and tenacious on scent, these friendly, affectionate hounds settle down nicely at home.",
    "imageName": "pharaoh_hound"
},
{
    "id": "ii32jj887hhg99",
    "name": "Scottish Terrier",
    "description": "A solidly compact dog of vivid personality, the Scottish Terrier is an independent, confident companion of high spirits. Scotties have a dignified, almost-human character.",
    "imageName": "scottish_terrier"
},
{
    "id": "jj32jj887hhg99",
    "name": "Tosa",
    "description": "A solidly compact dog of vivid personality, the Scottish Terrier is an independent, confident companion of high spirits. Scotties have a dignified, almost-human character.",
    "imageName": "tosa"
}
```

[image: This is an image of the errors I got after adding in the code that was commented]

[image]

Comment: Which fatal error is getting hit in your code example?

Comment: I updated my code to show where it is

Comment: have your asset contains `dutch_shepherd ` image ??

Comment: It looks like a typo error?. U miss } on line 13 , end of the code

Comment: My preview continues to crash